# ¿Se usa "por" en sus países en este caso?

Tags: preposiciones

La oración en cuestión es:

1. **Por** ser escritor, escribe bastante mal.

como equivalente a:

2. **Para** ser escritor, escribe bastante mal.

En mi lugar, se usan ambas, pero tal vez (2) sea más habitual. El sentido es: Escribe bastante mal **para** ser considerado escritor.

La pregunta es si, en sus respectivos lugares, se usan ambas preposiciones o solo "para".

Comment: Yo lo reduciría a dos frases arquetípicas que dejan ver la diferencia (no la equivalencia):
 - _Por ser analfabeto, escribe bastante mal_.
 - _Para ser analfabeto, escribe bastante bien_.

Comment: @aerobiomat Gracias. Mi pregunta se debe a que, a veces, se usa ese "por" como un "considerando" que no es causal sino adversativo: Considerando que es analfabeto, escribe bastante bien.

Answer (score 3):

A mi entender ambas frases tienen un significado diferente.

> Por ser escritor, escribe bastante mal.

Aquí se da por sentado que es escritor.

---

> Para ser escritor, escribe bastante mal.

Este caso **duda** si es escritor o no, ya que escribe bastante mal para que alguien pueda suponer que lo es.

Comment: Buen punto. Gracias

Comment: para ser escritor de da por sentado ser escritor? A mi, me parece que todavia no lo es.

Comment: Es lo que puse en la respuesta: "para ser escritor" pone en duda que lo sea

Answer (score 1):

In some circumstances, I listen people using both prepositions as equivalents, for example:

> Por (para) mí está bien.

> Es por (para) el bien del pueblo.

However, this is not the case. Your first sentence makes me think this one as equivalent:

> **Porque es** escritor, escribe mal.

So I think only your second sentence is right for the meaning you want to convey. Just my opinion.

Comment: para ser escritor parece que todavia no lo es.

Comment: @Lambie I think he could either be a writer or not. With the use of *para* the speaker does not affirm or deny that he is a writer, so the listener doesn't have that information

Comment: Para ser intérprete, hay que hablar por lo menos dos idiomas. Por ser intérprete, habla dos idiomas. por y para no son la misma cosa. Por nada.

Comment: @Lambie Never said that. And in your example with *para* , you are using it as a conditional "if you want to be an interpreter ...", which is different from the example of the question. On the other hand, a condition is just a condition: you are not affirming or denying anything with a conditional

Comment: Dices que son igual, según ciertos locutores. No estoy de acuerdo.

Comment: @Lambie No, I say that sometimes and in some circumstances people use it as equivalents. Not that they are the same. I will edit the answer for your better understanding

Comment: No creo que se utilisa como equivalente. Solo por los que no tienen formación.

Comment: @Lambie [https://www.redalyc.org/journal/921/92153510015/html/](https://www.redalyc.org/journal/921/92153510015/html/) "*En los ejemplos dados a continuación se podría sustituir una preposición por otra, prácticamente sin cambio de sentido, a excepción del hecho de que posiblemente el uso de por implique en la mente del hablante un leve matiz causal.*"

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión (al menos en Argentina). Tienen significados diferentes. Si dices

"Por ser escritor, escribe bastante mal."

estarías diciendo que escribe bastante mal *a causa* de ser escritor. Suena bastante contradictorio, pero significaría eso. Por lo que yo usaría, la segunda

"Para ser escritor, escribe bastante mal.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque Danielillo ya ha respondido como representante del español de España, disiento un poco de su respuesta.

Para mí

> Por ser escritor, escribe bastante mal

no suena bien y no se usa como equivalente de

> Para ser escritor, escribe bastante mal

No coincido con su opinión de que esta segunda exprese duda sobre si la persona es escritor o no, sino sobre la calidad de su trabajo; es decir, tanto si se autodenomina escritor como si le han publicado libros, escribe bastante mal. No se pone en tela de juicio el oficio, se da por validado.

La frase con **para** sería más o menos equivalente a

> Se supone que es escritor pero escribe bastante mal